# CImage destructor in DLL blocks the whole MFC program

Tags: c++, dll, mfc, gdi+

I am using a MFC dialog DLL, called in my main project when a button is pressed. In this DLL, I use GDI+ to display and resize an image, in the following function:

```
#include "atlimage.h"

void CPhysicsDialogDlg::displayImage()
{
    CImage img1;
    img1.Load(m_pathText);
    m_imgSize.x = img1.GetWidth();
    m_imgSize.y = img1.GetHeight();
    CDC *screenDC = GetDC();
    CDC mDC;
    mDC.CreateCompatibleDC(screenDC);
    CBitmap b;
    b.CreateCompatibleBitmap(screenDC, IMAGE_DISPLAY_WIDTH, IMAGE_DISPLAY_HEIGHT);

    CBitmap *pob = mDC.SelectObject(&b);
    mDC.SetStretchBltMode(HALFTONE);
    img1.StretchBlt(mDC.m_hDC, 0, 0, IMAGE_DISPLAY_WIDTH, IMAGE_DISPLAY_HEIGHT, 0, 0,
        img1.GetWidth(), img1.GetHeight(), SRCCOPY);
    mDC.SelectObject(pob);

    m_picture.SetBitmap((HBITMAP)b.Detach());
    ReleaseDC(screenDC);
}
```

However, when this function is called, the whole program completely freezes. In debug mode, when I try to pause and run it, the following message is displayed by Visual Studio:

> The process appears to be deadlocked (or is not running any user-mode
>   code). All threads have been stopped

While debugging, I found out that it comes from the `ReleaseGDIPlus` function in the `atlimage.h` file, called in the `CImage` destructor:

```
inline void CImage::CInitGDIPlus::ReleaseGDIPlus() throw()
{
    EnterCriticalSection(&m_sect);
    if( m_dwToken != 0 )
    {
        Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown( m_dwToken ); // this line freezes everything
    }
    m_dwToken = 0;
    LeaveCriticalSection(&m_sect);
}
```

The fun part is that when I run this single dialog as an EXE instead of calling it as a DLL, everyting works fine.

I tried to do the GDI+ startup and shutdown explicitly in the function, same problem:

```
void CPhysicsDialogDlg::displayImage()
{
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    //function code

    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2005 and Windows 7.

So the question is: why is the `ReleaseGDIPlus` function blocking, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reasons are the following:

1. You have to initialize/uninitialize GDI+ outside of DLL and do it only once
2. GDI+ is not thread safe. So you should use it in main app thread only.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using your DLL inside MFC application you should:

initialize it within InitInstance

uninitialize it within ExitInstance.

Anyway, it should be done only once and within main thread.

Answer (score 1):

We got the problem now too when a totally unrelated regular MFC DLL is being unloaded. Somehow this mixes up the shutdown code. I think MS makes a mistake here by putting GDI+ init and shutdown in a global object (CInitGDIPlus), thereby enhancing the risk that GDI+ is shutdown in DllMain. This is exactly against their own set of rules.

There was a kb article (Q322909) about this. Problem still present in VS2013.

Researching further it turns out that regular DLL's (which have their own CWinApp instance) in combination with MFC as a shared DLL messes up MFC's global administration. The AfxGlobalsAddRef / AfxGlobalsRelease uses a global reference count. MFC releases its resources when the ref count goes to zero. Amongst those resources are GDI+ resources (e.g. CPngImage which uses CImage). The GDI+ shutdown code may be invoked in this process. Since the ref count now only drops to zero when a regular MFC DLL gets unloaded, the GDI+ shutdown code is effectively invoked during DllMain time, resulting in a hang. Seems like a bug of MFC.

A solution might be to release the DLL's prematurely. If they are COM components one can use 'CoFreeUnusedLibrariesEx'. If you are linking implicitly there is no work around I guess.

See https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1470256/mfc-hangs-when-unloading-a-regular-dll-when-using-gdi

See https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/246188/msconnect-1470256mfc-hangs-when-unloading-a-regula.html (MS has closed connect).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MFC as a shared DLL, make sure you're calling `__super::InitInstance` in your override of `CWinApp::InitInstance` (you should have a class that derives from `CWinApp` and overrides both `InitInstance` and `ExitInstance`). This will tell MFC that you need the globals until you call `__super::ExitInstance`, making sure they're not released by other DLLs!